# Conditional statement using .removeClass(); in a .show(); and .hide(); function

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, show-hide

**Scenario:** I have created a simple Show/Hide function that allows the user to click on an IMG and display the subsequent content.

**Expected Behavior:** When the user clicks on an IMG, `.service-img`, I would like the selected IMG content, `.service-content`, to `.addClass('fadeIn');` while `.removeClass('fadeIn');` from the previously selected/visible content.

**Issue:** Although the conditional is successful at `.addClass('fadeIn');` it fails at `.removeClass('fadeIn');` It seems to add the class to all `.service-content` when the `.service-img` is clicked.

***My Assumption:*** Although I am asking `if ($('.service-content').is(':visible')) .addClass etc...` I can never really remove the class because technically `.service-content` is always visible when `.service-img` is clicked.

***Question:*** How can I properly write the conditional to check if the ***Current selected element*** `.is(':visible')` then execute function, regardless if all content elements share the same class name.

**A few, semi-successful attempts**

```
// Function Attempt 1 shows .service-content but adds .fadeIn 
// to .service-img so service content never Fades Into view  
$('.service-content').hide();
$('.service-content:first-child').show();
$('.service-img').click(function() {
  $('.service-content').hide(); 
  $('.service-content').eq($(this).index()).show();
  if ($('.service-content').is(':visible')) {
    $(this).addClass('fadeIn')
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('fadeIn');
  }
});

// Function Attempt 2
$('.service-content').hide();
$('.service-content:first-child').show();
$('.service-img').click(function() {
  $('.service-content').hide(); 
  $('.service-content').eq($(this).index()).show();
  if ($('.service-content').is(':visible')) {
    $('.service-content').addClass('fadeIn')
  } else {
    $('.service-content').removeClass('fadeIn');
  }
});

// Function Attempt 3
$('.service-content').hide();
$('.service-content:first-child').show();
$('.service-img').click(function() {
  $('.service-content').hide(); 
  $('.service-content').eq($(this).index()).show();
  if ($('.service-content').eq($(this).index()).is(':visible')) {
    $('.service-content').eq($(this).index()).addClass('fadeIn')
  } else {
    $('.service-content').eq($(this).index()).removeClass('fadeIn');
  }
});
```

Here is the complete prototype: [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/WeebleWobb/tc9L1k14/18/)

Comment: Will this fiddle fix your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/tc9L1k14/21/

Comment: No toggleClass() function does not work. I'm not seeing the fadeIn class executing when you click between elements. The desired effect is to add fadeIn class to content, causing it to fadeIn, then remove the class fadeIn when a different IMG is clicked, causing it to fadeIn etc...etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to check if the element is visible. I guess that this would do the trick.

https://jsfiddle.net/3fbzrto0/30/

```js
$('.service-img').on('click', function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    var content = $('.service-content').eq(index);
    //hide all visible elements
    $('.service-content').hide();
    $('.service-content').removeClass('fadeIn');

    content.show();
    content.addClass('fadeIn');
});
```

Comment: This function works but all `.service-content` are visible but do no have the fadeIn class added to them. This causes all the divs to stack vertically with `opactiy:0` then when clicked `.fadeIn` but to their current position in the vertical stack order. **[See JS Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/WeebleWobb/3fbzrto0/)**

Comment: @WeebleWobb, sorry, i have edited my answer. Please check the fiddle in it.

Comment: Although both answers achieved my expected behavior, this answer utilized variables and helped me better understand variables best practices and the [_Don't Repeat Yourself_ philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 1):

I think before you show the newly selected element, you need to remove the earlier one first. i.e. `removeClass` should come before `addClass`.

```
$('.service-content').removeClass('fadeIn');    //Assuming this will remove class fadeIn from all elements.
$('.service-content').eq($(this).index()).show();
if ($('.service-content').eq($(this).index()).is(':visible')) {
        $('.service-content').eq($(this).index()).addClass('fadeIn')
      }
```

Comment: Moving `$('.service-content').removeClass('fadeIn');` before `.show()` seems to work. It allows the fadeIn class to execute on repeated clicks. 

I noticed when I pulled up Chrome Inspector and tried the function, the fadeIn class never removes itself from .service-content but still executes the fadeIn animation. Is this because the function runs so fast the fadeIn removal isn't physically visible in inspector or could this cause some issues?

Comment: That's right, to verify you can put some delay before `.show()`